# I can't turn off debug bar in Laravel on production

Tags: php, laravel, debugging, production-environment

I have set

```
'enabled' = false
```

in both package and in config/debugbar.php

I cleared cache with

```
php artisan cache:clear
```

but I still see it on production environment.
I accidently commited

```
'enabled' = false
```

by accident and can't turn it off. I even rolled back commits, but that doesn't help. Any ideas?

@edit the .env has also debug set to false

@edit2 also when I got ot /login route on new browser (or private mode) I don't see the bar, but when I refresh this page, it is there again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution for 5.5 and above**

Install the package with:

```
composer require barryvdh/laravel-debugbar:dev-master
```

Because of the package auto-discovery feature, you don't need to add package's service provider to the `providers` list in `config/app.php` and Debugbar will only be loaded in the development environment.

**Solution for 5.4 and below**

Put this code to the `AppServiceProvider@register`:

```
if ($this->app->isLocal()) {
    $this->app->register('Barryvdh\Debugbar\ServiceProvider');
}
```

Don't forget to remove Laravel Debugbar line from `config/app.php` providers section.

After doing this, Laravel Debugbar will only be loaded in a local environment.

Comment: I did it, but that didn't help. What does it do to turn OFF the debugbar?

Comment: @ZbigniewKisły if you're on 5.5, look at updated answer. Also, try to clear view cache with `php artisan view:clear`

Comment: barryvdh/laravel-debugbar v3.0.0 supports Laravel 5.5 + Auto Discovery, but it is not helping to disable it on EC2

Answer (score 12):

#### Go To `.env` And Set

`DEBUGBAR_ENABLED=false`

#### OR

`APP_DEBUG=false`

Comment: best answer simple env change

Answer (score 11):

It is not a matter of debugbar, it is general problem with .env. You can change your APP_NAME to see that it is not changing anything.

To apply your new config changes including .env changes you need to run artisan command in your project folder:

```
php artisan config:cache
```

Answer (score 6):

Did u try changing it in the .env file?

Look for the value `APP_DEBUG` in the .env file and set it `false`.

Out of the box, .env has it set to `true`.

Comment: it works on my vagrant homestead, but it is not working on ec2

Comment: Its working on ec2, try clearing the config with **php artisan config:clear**

Answer (score 0):

if you are on 5.4 you can do under AppServiceProvider as follows:

```
public function register()
{
/*
 * Sets third party service providers that are only needed on local/testing environments
 */
if ($this->app->environment() != 'production') {
/**
 * Loader for registering facades.
 */
$loader = \Illuminate\Foundation\AliasLoader::getInstance();
/*
 * Load third party local aliases
 */
$loader->alias('Debugbar', \Barryvdh\Debugbar\Facade::class);
}
}
```

if you want full control under 5.5 you can do in the same AppServiceProvider:

```
public function register()
{
    /*
     * Sets third party service providers that are only needed on local/testing environments
     */
    if ($this->app->environment() != 'production') {
        /**
         * Loader for registering facades.
         */
        $loader = \Illuminate\Foundation\AliasLoader::getInstance();

        /*
         * Load third party local providers
         */
        $this->app->register(\Barryvdh\Debugbar\ServiceProvider::class);

        /*
         * Load third party local aliases
         */
        $loader->alias('Debugbar', \Barryvdh\Debugbar\Facade::class);
    }
}
```

and under composer.json in the extra:

```
"extra": {
    "laravel": {
        "dont-discover": [
            "barryvdh/laravel-debugbar"
        ]
    }
},
```

Then you are good to go and enable and disable via .env, if it's different of production it will be enabled (local, testing, etc..) if it's on production it will be automatically disabled.

Hope it helps, good luck!